# MySQL SHA256 with Insert Statement

Tags: mysql, string, hash, insert

I want to create a script to fill a database for testing. How would I set a string to be hashed and the inserted into the database?

I have:

```
INSERT INTO `loop`.`User`
(`userID`,
`firstName`,
`lastName`,
`email`,
`password`,
`userName`,
`bio`,
`spamCount`)
VALUES
('gZvTtlPtjGRqeMBaLji3HxoKB5EZCsNL',
'Joe',
'Smith',
'test0@email.com',
SHA2('testgZvTtlPtjGRqeMBaLji3HxoKB5EZCsNL', 256),
'test0@email.com',
"TEST BIO",
0);
```

How do I hash the string and INSERT in same statement?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 37):

You can insert a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` to run a function on one of the inputs:

```
INSERT INTO `loop`.`User`
(`userID`,
 `firstName`,
 `lastName`,
 `email`,
 `password`,
 `userName`,
 `bio`,
 `spamCount`)
SELECT
'gZvTtlPtjGRqeMBaLji3HxoKB5EZCsNL',
'Joe',
'Smith',
'test0@email.com',
SHA2('testgZvTtlPtjGRqeMBaLji3HxoKB5EZCsNL', 256),
'test0@email.com',
"TEST BIO",
0;
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? I want to understand.

Comment: When you insert `VALUES` they have to be straight up values (strings, integers, etc.) rather than functions or subqueries that resolve to values. When using a `SELECT` statement, however, one is not constrained in this way.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you **already have the table filled by some content**, you can alter it with the following :

```
ALTER TABLE `page` ADD COLUMN `hash` char(64) AS (SHA2(`content`, 256)) AFTER `content`
```

This solution will add `hash` column right after the `content` one, **generates hash for existing and new records** too without need to change your INSERT statement.